# What are some options for securing redis db?

Tags: ruby, redis, resque

I'm running Redis locally and have multiple machines communicating with redis on the same port -- any suggestions for good ways to lock down access to Redis? The database is run on Mac OS X. Thank you.

Edit: This is assuming I do not want to use the built-in (non backwards compatible) Redis requirepass directive in the config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On EC2 we lock down the machines that can make requests to the redis port on our redis box to only be our app box (we also only use it to store non-sensitive data).

Another option could be to not open up the redis port externally, but require doing [port forwarding through an ssh tunnel](http://www.debianadmin.com/howto-use-ssh-local-and-remote-port-forwarding.html).  Then you could only allow requests coming through the tunnel and only allow ssh with a known key.

You'd pay the ssh penalty, but maybe that's ok for your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple `requirepass` directive in the configuration file which allow access only to clients who authenticate through [AUTH](http://redis.io/commands/auth) command. I recommend to read docs on this command, namely the "note" section.

Comment: Yeah I saw this one. Let me modify my original question - curious if there are other solutions.

Comment: @Mike: Currently I know only about this one.